# Refresh page at intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, page-refresh

I am Using the following code to refresh the webpage at particular interval. The page seems to refresh but the Google Analytics code is not getting loaded. I have the Google Analytics code also for reference below. I am still a newbie to coding, Would be really great if you could help figure out why the Analytics code is not loading.

Refresh Code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh_handler() {
    function refresh() {
       var url = $(location).attr('href');
       window.history.pushState("", "<?php echo $meta_title; ?>", url);
       $("#ajaxanalytics").load("http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/inc-analytics.php"); 
    }
    setInterval(refresh, 60*1000); //every 1 minutes
}
$(document).ready(refresh_handler);
</script>
```

Analytics Code

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you can achieve this by placing below meta tag into head tag of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="30">
```

Comment: I dont want the users to get annoyed when the page refreshes. The code above code refreshes the page without the users knowing the page has refreshed. Also I would like the page refreshes to show up in the analytics

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing with script only refreshed part of your page. You cannot change analytic with that, except with meta tag, reload whole page and this is a bad way rank up your analytic data. 
As far as I know, Google Analytic have a tracking tools estimate how long user on your page, how many bouncing etc.
But I don't know if your web only have one page, paralax or something.